# Chong Wei's B sample being tested

Tags: grammar

> *Chong Wei's B sample **being tested**, faces agonising wait for result.*

What does the "being" means in the sentence above?
Is it means the sample is still testing?

Reference: [thestar.com.my](http://www.thestar.com.my/News/Nation/2014/11/05/Chong-wei-B-sample-test/)

Comment: Check out previous questions tagged [tag:headlinese].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it means that the sample is currently undergoing testing while Chong Wei waits.

It's a good example of journalism-ese.  News editors (even in the age of the internet) often need to shorten or abbreviate a statement so that it can fit into a given amount of space.  In this case the shortening is quite severe, so much so that someone unfamiliar with the story has a hard time figuring out what it is about.

In proper English this would be:

> Chong Wei's B sample is being tested; until the result is released, he faces an agonizing wait.

Comment: Even in the 'corrected' version, it's hard to understand to a layman because "B sample" means nothing >_<

Comment: @Doc He had two samples, presumably, A and B.  They tested A and found something suspicious, now they're testing B for confirmation.